# How to ensure that Camel's ProducerTemplate waits for CamelContext to start

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am trying to use the @EndpointInject annotation in order to create a ProducerTemplate to bridge my POJO to the CamelContext (as described here http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html).

The problem that I am running into is that the ProducerTemplate is injected into my POJO before all routes in the camel context are started. So when I call producerTemplate.send(...), I get a `DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint...` error.

Is there anything that I need to do in order to ensure the CamelContext is started before trying to send to a route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `block=true` as an option on the direct endpoint and it will wait until the consumer is active and running. This should help.

- http://camel.apache.org/direct

Otherwise you would need to write some code yourself to wait until the `CamelContext` is in started state. You can get access to it from the injected `ProducerTemplate` which has a `getCamelContext`.

Also another alternative is to have the dependency injection framework, if possible, setup your bean *after* Camel. If you are using spring xml, then it has the `depends-on` attribute you can set on the `<bean>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think `block=true` is the best option here. I was also able to get it working by doing something like this:  ```while(!camelContext.getStatus().isStarted() {  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);  
 }```  
but that is a little messy...   `depends-on` did not seem to work properly for me (probably because the camel context starts up asynchronously).

Comment: block=true only available from 2.11.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your response Claus Ibsen the question is about producer not a consumer.
My suggestion use spring event

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void onApplicationEvent() {
    producerTemplate.sendBody("demo");

}
```